# Android native code memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, java-native-interface

I started profiling my app with Android Studio 3.0. It allows to view how many native code is allocated. My app doesn't use native code. After launching several times one activity heap dump showed that no activity was leaked, but native heap increased and java heap didn't.

Any solutions?

Comment: I would like to know this too.